# android_core-tutorial fails with "Trying out the new apps"

Tags: ros, android-core, tutorial, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have done the tutorial at [www.ros.org/wiki/android_core](http://www.ros.org/wiki/android_core)  until point "3.3 Running a tutorial app"

But executing point "4.2 If it's your first time using this working copy, configure it:"

(./tools/configure.py) fails with an error
altough in the same dir I can sucessfully execute roscd into android_core:

everybody@RitterROSt:~/work4Android/osrf_rosandroid$ ./tools/configure.py
[rosstack] Error: stack/package android_core not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/configure.py", line 13, in <module>
    android_core_path = subprocess.check_output(['rosstack', 'find', 'android_core']).strip()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 544, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['rosstack', 'find', 'android_core']' returned non-zero exit status 1
everybody@RitterROSt:~/work4Android/osrf_rosandroid$ roscd android_core
everybody@RitterROSt:~/work4Android/android_core$

What is going wrong here and how to fix it?

Much much thanks in advance.

Jens

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62803/android_core-tutorial-fails-with-%22trying-out-the-new-apps%22/) by [mcl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4901/mcl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-05-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was able to get passed this error, by modifying the file
tools/configure.py line 13 to:
android_core_path = subprocess.check_output(['rospack', 'find', 'android_core']).strip()

However, I encountered other problems:
[javac] /home/liyang/work/android_groovy_ws/osrf_rosandroid/android_app_chooser/src/org/ros/android/android_app_chooser/AppChooser.java:67: package org.ros.android.robotapp does not exist

Looks like the directory robotapp is missing from source, or my CLASSPATH is not pointing to the right place.

Can someone help out on this?

Thanks in advance

---

Originally posted by [liyang](https://answers.ros.org/users/5091/liyang/) with karma: 16 on 2013-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0